# An answer of mine which attracted 4 positive votes has been deleted and I have no idea why

Tags: discussion, deleted-posts

See the question on hallowe'en. I've no idea why [my answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/133831/8360) has been deleted! Please would someone tell me why this has happened.

Comment: People will upvote anything. Your response was interesting story about halloween but wasn't an answer to the question.

Comment: @Mitch So does that mean you believe in the divine right of kings?

Comment: Ha ha. Actually, I don't know what you mean. Divine? Kings? What year is this?

Answer (score 5):

It was deleted because it was too long to be a comment and it didn't answer the question.

Comment: What a capricious outlook you exhibit! My answer was making a perfectly valid point, namely that commercial interests drive Hallowe'en, and we would certainly not be celebrating the occasion in Britian were it not for the likes of Tesco and Sainsbury who jolly everyone into making inane remarks like 'Happy Hallowe'en! What in the world do they know about the practice of Hallowing?

Comment: @WS2; 'Making a point' is fine on a forum but not in a field marked 'Your answer to the question'.